# Android studio not allowing multiple deployments at once when running test

Tags: android, android-studio, automated-tests

I know how to deploy my app to multiple devices at once as long as it is not in debug mode, but is there anyway to deploy multiple tests at once in Android Studio? It seems like it is disabled on purpose but I would like to know if there is some kind of work around to get this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Spoon?

http://square.github.io/spoon/

It will allow you to test your apps to multiple device while also generate a report (HTML) for you.

Comment: Ill accept this because they offer a great solution, would be great if there was a better work around within Android Studio though